# The Möbius number of the nonabelian finite simple groups

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, enumerative-combinatorics, algebraic-combinatorics

Let $L$ be a finite lattice with minimum $\hat{0}$ and maximum $\hat{1}$. The  Möbius function $\mu$ for $L$ is defined recursively by: for  $\forall a,b \in L$ with $a<b$,  $\mu(b,b) = 1$ and $\mu(a,b) = -\sum_{a<c\le b}\mu(c,b)$.
The Möbius number of $L$ is defined by $\mu(\hat{0},\hat{1})$.

Define the Möbius number $\mu(G)$ of a finite group $G$ to be the Möbius number of its subgroup lattice. For the nonabelian finite simple groups of small order, we observe that $$\mu(G) \in |G| \mathbb{Z}$$

**Question**: Is it true for any nonabelian finite simple group?

*Remark:* It is true if $|G| < 100000$ (see the table below).

It's false for nonsimple groups because for $p$ (odd) prime, $\mu(S_p) = p!/2$ ([[S]](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S009731659792762X)) and  $\mu(C^2_p) = p$.

---

Table for the nonabelian finite simple groups of order $< 100000$:
$$ \begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
G & |G| & \mu(G) & \mu(G)/|G| & |Out(G)| & \newline 
 \hline  
  A_5 & 60     &  -60  & -1 & 2 & \newline 
 \hline  
  PSL(2,7) & 168    &  0 & 0 & 2&   \newline 
 \hline
  A_6 & 360     &   720   & 2 & 4 & \newline 
 \hline
  PSL(2,8) & 504     &   -504   & -1 & 3  \newline 
 \hline
PSL(2,11) & 660     &  660 & 1 & 2 \newline 
 \hline
PSL(2,13) & 1092     &  -1092 & -1 & 2 \newline 
 \hline
  PSL(2,17) & 2448    &   0 & 0 & 2 \newline 
 \hline
  A_7 & 2520        &  2520 & 1 & 2  \newline 
 \hline
  PSL(2,19)& 3420     &   3420 & 1 & 2 \newline 
 \hline
  PSL(2,16)& 4080     &  0 & 0 & 4 \newline 
 \hline
  PSL(3,3)& 5616      &  0 & 0 & 2 \newline
 \hline
   PSU(3,3)& 6048     &  0 & 0 & 2 \newline
 \hline
  PSL(2,23)& 6072     &  0 & 0 & 2 \newline
 \hline
   PSL(2,25)& 7800    &  0 & 0 & 4 \newline
 \hline
   M_{11} & 7920      &   -7920 & -1 & 1 \newline
 \hline
  PSL(2,27)& 9828     &   9828 & 1 & 6 \newline
 \hline
   PSL(2,29) & 12180 &   12180 & 1 & 2 \newline
 \hline
  PSL(2,27)& 14880 &   29760 & 2 & 2 \newline
 \hline
  A_8& 20160 &   20160 & 1 & 2 \newline
 \hline
  PSL(3,4)& 20160 &   -120960 & -6 & 12 \newline
 \hline
  PSL(2,37)& 25308&   -25308& -1 & 2 \newline
 \hline
PSp(4,3)& 25920& -25920& -1   & 2  \newline
 \hline
Sz(8)& 29120& -29120& -1   & 3  \newline
 \hline
PSL(2,32)& 32736& -32736& -1   & 5  \newline
 \hline
PSL(2,41)& 34440& 68880& 2   & 2  \newline
 \hline
PSL(2,43)& 39732& -39732& -1   & 2  \newline
 \hline
PSL(2,47)& 51888& 0& 0   &  2 \newline
 \hline
PSL(2,49)& 58800& 117600& 2   &  4 \newline
 \hline
PSU(3,4)& 62400& 0& 0   & 4  \newline
 \hline
 PSL(2,53)& 74412& -74412& -1  & 2  \newline
 \hline
M_{12}   & 95040 &  95040  & 1  & 2  \newline
\end{array}$$

Comment: I believe the fact that $\mu(1,S_p)=\frac{p!}{2}$ when $p$ is prime was known well before I published the paper you link to above.  I think it appears in a paper of Pahlings.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer to your question is ``yes".  Something more general was proved by Hawkes, Isaacs and \"Ozaydin in a 1989 paper in the Rocky Mountain Journal of Mathematics.

CORRECTION: As Sebastien Palcoux notes below, this result is due to Kratzer and Th\'evenaz

More precise results for the groups $PSL_2(p)$ were known to Philip Hall, and $PSL_2(q)$ was handled by Martin Downs, as were the Suzuki groups.

Some results on symmetric groups appear in a paper of mine, and other classes of ``small" almost simple groups are addressed in my thesis,

http://www.math.wustl.edu/~shareshi/thmsri.ps

(Sorry, it is a postscript file and some non-mathematical pages are repeated.)

Comment: I don't know how to deduce it from the paper Hawkes, Isaacs and Özaydin (available [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rmjm/1250125848)), but by browsing your thesis, I've found Theorem 1.5 refering to Théorème 3.1. of the paper "Fonction de Möbius d'un groupe fini et anneau de Burnside" (1984) by Kratzer and Thévenaz (available [here](https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/130417/files/fulltext.pdf)) and stating that $$\mu(G) \in \frac{|G|}{|G:G'|_0} \mathbb{Z}.$$ The result follows immediately for any perfect group.

Comment: You have the right reference, my memory was incorrect.

Comment: I should mention also that Emilio Pierro has handled some Ree groups, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.8702.pdf

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux: Theorem 4.5 in the Hawkes-Isaacs-Özaydin paper says that $ |N_G(H):H | $ divides $ m \mu(H,G)$, where $m$ is the square-free part of $ |G:G'H | $. Of course, the case $ H=1$ is the result of Kratzer and Thévenaz.

Comment: @FriederLadisch: Nice! In others words: $$\mu(H,G) \in \frac{|N_G(H):H |}{|G:G'H |_0} \mathbb{Z}.$$

Comment: @FriederLadisch: but Theorem 3.1 of Kratzer-Thévenaz states also that $$\mu(H,G) \in \frac{|N_G(H):H |}{|G:G' |_0} \mathbb{Z}.$$ Note that $G'H$ is replaced by $G'$. Can we deduce one from the other?

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux: I would say that the result of Hawkes-Isaacs-Özaydin is stronger, since $ |G:G'H|$ always divides $|G:G'|$ ?

Comment: @FriederLadisch: Yes! By the product formula $$\frac{|G:G'|}{|G:G'H|} =  \frac{|G'H|}{|G'|} = \frac{|H|}{|G' \cap H|} \in \mathbb{N}.$$